# How to put multiple Bootstrap inputs on same line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="watch" value="" placeholder="watch">

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" value="" placeholder="Price (optional)" style="width: 140px;">
</div>

<span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update($(this));"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Update</span>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2gdxmt3z/1/)

It renders like this:

[image]

How can I get both inputs and the button on the same line? I've been messing with the CSS but can't seem to get it to work. I was able to get it working with a table, but I know a CSS solution would be "better."

Comment: It's called inline form: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Inline Forms like in the Bootstrap Documentation found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-inline

The 'form-inline' class is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 17):

**Solution 1 - Using the Grid**

Use the Bootstrap’s predefined grid classes for arranging the form elements.

The grid gives you a better control over the width of the elements and scales better than the Inline Form solution.

[image: Grid form example]

```
<form>
<div class="form-row"> 

   <div class="form-group col-md-7">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="watch" value="" placeholder="watch">
    </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">$</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price0" placeholder="Price (optional)">
   </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update($(this));"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update</button>
  </div>

</div>
</form>
```

**Solution 2: Inline Form**:

Use an Inline Form, as described by [Bootstrap Inline Form Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms).
You need to manually address the width and alignment.

[image: Inline Form snapshot]

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="watch" value="" placeholder="watch">
  </div>

  <div class="input-group m-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">$</div>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price (optional)">
  </div>  

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2" onclick="update($(this));"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update</button>
</form>
```

**Running Example**

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/addmoss/caLe09oj/62/) shows both solutions running.

The sample code and fiddle are updated for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 3):

Use grid layout with `xs` phone size to force grid on responsive, the grid is divided into 12 cells so you'll need 3 x 4.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   </div>
</div>
```

You could also have one of them bigger than the others:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-7">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
   </div>
</div>
```

As long as they add up to 12.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2gdxmt3z/2/)

[Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you use multiple

```
<div class="col"></div>
```